# Alternative definition of factor space

Tags: vector-spaces

In the typical definition of a (vector) factor space $V/W$, one defines (one could also go through the process of defining these affine subsets as appropriate equivalence classes)
$$(v+W)+(v'+W) = (v+v') +W$$
$$a(v+W) = av + W.$$
I'm wondering if it's possible, rather than just making these definitions (and showing that they are well-defined/independent of the member of the given affine subset), to actually connect them to underlying operations on the subsets. That is, one usually has defined at this point the sum of subsets as $A + B = \{a+b \mid a \in A, \, b \in B\}$ and scalar multiplication as $xA = \{xa \mid a \in A\}$. Then one can show that the sum is associative and that the scalar multiplication distributes, and thereby recover the original definitions as theorems? If this works, why isn't this usually done?

Edit: In this context, the singleton $\{v\}$ would often be written simply as $v$, as above in the original definitions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is possible. These are equivalent definitions. Defining it using the usual addition and scalar operations of subsets is maybe a bit less intuitive though. The reason why cosets are interesting is because of the equivalence relation. The whole idea of the quotient is "collapsing" the space by identifying all vectors in $W$ with the zero vector.

But the main reason why the first definition is more common is that while the two definitions are equivalent for vector spaces, they are not equivalent anymore in some other algebraic structures, like in rings. (where a quotient is defined similarly) So defining the operations using representatives is something which you can also generalize.